# VSCode: How to keep some, but not all, project settings under version control?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, python-venv

My team use VSCode to edit a Python project and I'd like to keep some of the project settings under version control (we use Git). But I'd also like to leave some project settings free to be customized by each developer.

I've already commited the `.vscode/settings.json` configuration. It has the project standard configuration:

- code formatter to be used
- level of type checking
- linter selection
- test framework used

But some configurations should be left to the developer. Our greatest problem is with the **Python interpreter**. We are using the standard *venv* module for our virtual environments. So we must tell VSCode which interpreter it must use.

Our envs are created in the same directory of the project and put in `.gitignore`. The main problem is that venv has a different structure if you are in Windows or in Linux. In Windows, we must use the interpreter located in `Scripts/python.exe` and in Linux we must use `bin/python`.

Beyond the interpreter setting, it would be nice if each developer could have his/her own preferences not commited in the repository.

Is it possible to have more than one VSCode project settings file and just one of them commited?

Comment: If you are not in a Multi Root Workspace you can store some of the settings in the `.code-workspace` file. Create a Multi Root Workspace with one folder. Or you can put them there for Multi Root Workspace and not put that file in `.gitignore`. You can also store them in the Global User settings. If you install VSC Insiders you have 2 independent VSC settings, to be used for different Python developement

Comment: @rioV8 it would give me a ugly workspace, but may be a viable hack. How do I find more info about these independent VSC settings?

Comment: there are 3 places where you can store settings: `Global User Settings`, `.code-workspace` file, Workspace folder `.vscode/settings.json`. https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WorkspaceConfiguration

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but a solution of my problem with a portable path for the *Python Interpreter*.

I started to create my virtual environments inside my repository in a directory called `.venv`. The interpreter path is configured with a path relative to the workspace root dir. I also add the path to my `.gitignore` file.

It works fine for everybody and also has the benefit of forcing everybody to use a virtual environment.